# AD DNS round robin - How to stop

Tags: directory

Below is the architecture of my Active Directory setup running on Windows 2008 R2. All the clients are Windows 7 32/64 bit.

[image: Current Active Directory Setup]

The setup is there are three sites and each site has its own Active Directory infrastructure with two servers. 
Clients and AD servers are in different subnets. Clients are in multiple subnets and is bound to AD using AD sites and services. All the sites are interconnected and does replication of AD and DNS.

I have a problem now with DNS round robin. My in-house application is based on DNS query to AD and based on the subnet it will go to the specific application server.

DNS round robin gives a specific IP of the dns in a round robin fashion, for example:

```
c:\> nslookup abc.com 

Name:    abc.com
Addresses:  192.168.0.51
          192.168.0.52
          172.31.100.52
          10.0.0.51
          172.31.100.51
          10.0.0.52
```

the next time,

```
c:\> nslookup abc.com 

Name:    abc.com
Addresses: 10.0.0.52
          192.168.0.52
          172.31.100.52
          10.0.0.51
          172.31.100.51
      192.168.0.51
```

and so on. This creates an issue with the application since it tries to go to the wrong server.

Now the actual problem, I tried to switch of the DNS round robin in the DNS snap-in by switching off

1. Enable netmask ordering
2. Enable round robin

Now, the DNS round robin does not happen but nslookup from clients go to a different site's DNS.

For example, client in site 1 returns nslookup as:

```
c:\> nslookup abc.com 

Name:    abc.com
Addresses: 192.168.0.52
          10.0.0.52
          172.31.100.52
          10.0.0.51
          172.31.100.51
      192.168.0.51
```

and always returns 192.168.0.52 IP address. How can I make the clients to query the same DNS in its site always? I am not sure if I can use netmask ordering using

```
dnscmd /confing
```

since AD and clients are in different subnet. Can any please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: This question is neck deep about networking and not about webmastering.

Comment: First of all, undo the changes you did because they are wrong. Second, I have some questions: Did you install an application on the domain controller? And does your client connect to the FQDN of AD domain? Depending on your setup, I can give you a fitting solution.